# Android studio. Как включить в пакет сервис, созданный в Qt?

Tags: android, qt

С Qt работаю очень давно, а вот недавно решил изучить программирование под андроид. 
На данный момент стоит задача написать некоторое приложение, функциональная часть (сервис) довольно сложная, а отображение (активити) - простое. Я решил написать активити в андроид студио, а сервис в Qt используя QAndroidService и QtService(для нативного кода).
Конечно, можно было бы сделать просто 2 приложения - активити и сервис с параметром exported, но это немного костыльный метод, да и для сервис требует некоторых разрешений, а для их установки нужно сделать первичный запуск.
В общем, как можно подключить сервис, созданный в Qt в проект Android studio?
Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Если вы подтянули Qt в Android, далее что-то тип:

**JAVA**

```
public class AndroidService extends QtService
{
}
```

дальше по документации:

> Uncomment the service part of your AndroidManifest.xml. Make sure the
>   service tag contains an android:process=":some_name" attribute. It is
>   needed to force the service to run in a separate process than the
>   activity. If you're using the same application (.so file) for activity
>   and also for service, you need to use android.app.arguments meta-data
>   to pass some arguments to your main function in order to know which
>   one is which. To enable background running, uncomment
>   android.app.background_running meta-data and set it to true
>   (android:value="true").

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
  <service android:process=":qt" android:name=".AndroidService">
    <meta-data android:name="android.app.background_running" android:value="true"/>
  </service>
```